# Open Chrome without it taking focus (Puppeteer)

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I'm using Puppeteer to launch multiple browsers - Every few minutes, it'll reopen the browsers. This works fine, except it's constantly opening browsers *and focusing the tabs,* bothering me while I'm trying to use the computer. Due to what I'm trying to do, I have a few specific problems that ruin any ideas I can come up with, like

- Don't close the browser, clear the cache! (I'm using a plugin that doesn't allow you to clear cache like this, it forces you to close + restart the browser)
- Use headless: true! (Again, due to my use case, the plugin sadly doesn't work with headless: true)

Tl;dr, I need a way to open a browser (that can be used in a Puppeteer) that won't take focus, without just setting headless:true

If you have any advice or ideas, that'd be awesome!

Edit: My OS is Windows

Comment: can you specify what is your OS?

Comment: My OS is Windows